# IoT Hub Routing Messages to Only One Partition of Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have a data pipeline set up in Azure where I send messages to an IoTHub which then routes those messages to an EventHub. When I read from the EventHub using the standard EventProcessorHost method, I find that only one of the partitions is being read from. I assume that only one partition is actually having messages routed to it. I have not specified a partition key anywhere and expect that the messages would be routed to all of the partitions of the event hub using round robin (as per the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide).

How can I configure my setup to route messages to all partitions of the event hub?

Comment: Is it possible you are only receiving data from one device? IoT Hub does automatic partitioning based on the deviceId, so the partition affinity might be the cause

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. I was sending a large number of messages to IoT Hub as a single device. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help. I will post the comment as an answer as well so it is more clean. If you accept it then others can see the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment:

Is it possible you are only receiving data from one device? IoT Hub does automatic partitioning based on the deviceId, so the partition affinity might be the cause.